# How to get sys_id from the result(incident_response) from below c# code

Tags: c#, json, servicenow

I have the following JSON(modified) which is read from a `HttpWebRequest` response stream, and I want to extract the value of `"sys_id"`:

```
{
  "result": {
    "number": "INC0012618",
    "opened_by": {
      "link": "//XXX.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user/38723e5ddb42f200deb8f6fcbf96196d",
      "value": "38723e5ddb42f200deb8f6fcbf96196d"
    },
    "sys_created_on": "2017-07-20 14:41:52",
    "sys_domain": {
      "link": "://XXX.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user_group/global",
      "value": "global"
    },
    "u_incident_summary": "",
    "business_service": {
      "link": "://xxx.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/cmdb_ci_service/IT services",
      "value": "IT services"
    },
    "work_end": "",
    "caller_id": {
      "link": "://xxxx.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user/71f5455d4f735e000d7f0ed11310c719",
      "value": "71f5455d4f735e000d7f0ed11310c719"
    },
    "close_code": "",
    "assignment_group": {
      "link": "://xxx.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user_group/9e158987dba27a007ea0f4e9bf961983",
      "value": "9e158987dba27a007ea0f4e9bf961983"
    },
    "sys_id": "7fb4e50edb8c0b007ea0f4e9bf9619ba",
    "u_outage_start_time": ""
  }
}
```

This is what I have tried so far, where `incident_responce` is a string containing the JSON above:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(incident_responce); 
var value = (string)jObject["sys_id"]; 
Console.WriteLine(value);
```

But, it didn't work, I think because there is `"result"` at the start.  How can I retrieve this value?

Comment: used this but it didnt worked because i think as there is result in starting             { string incident_responce  = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     var jObject = JObject.Parse(incident_responce);
     var value = (string)jObject["sys_id"];
     Console.WriteLine(value);}   please suggest.

Comment: The presence of backslashes there indicates that this is not JSON. You will have to use those backslashes in your code, but the output should look like `{"result":{ ... }}` without the backslashes. Are you getting this text from an API?

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, your initial attempt fails because `"sys_id"` is nested inside the `"result"` object:

```
{ "result": { ... "sys_id":"7fb4e50edb8c0b007ea0f4e9bf9619ba" } }
```

It's easier to see this if you indent and format your JSON, for instance by uploading it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Such a nested value can be queried directly by using [`JToken.SelectToken()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm):

```
var root = JToken.Parse(incident_responce); 
var value = (string)root.SelectToken("result.sys_id");
```

`SelectToken()` supports querying for values deep within the JSON container hierarchy using [JSONPath syntax](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  If the `"result.sys_id"` token is not found, `null` is returned.

Alternatively, you could use Json.NET's support for querying JSON hierarchies using [dynamic functionality](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm):

```
dynamic root = JToken.Parse(incident_responce); 
var value = (string)root.result.sys_id;
```

However, if the `"result"` token is not found, a `RuntimeBinderException` will be thrown instead of a `null` value returned.

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/L1crIs).